# v alias to open new buffer with tab completion

Tags: neovim

I have 'alias v="nvim"' in my zshrc, and when I'm inside neovim and want to open a new buffer I always start writting `:v path-to-file` then I realize and I have to change it for `:vi path-to-file`.

Is there a way to open a file with `v path-to-file` and retain tab completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, a conditional abbreviation on `:v` so that `:v`  expands to `:e` , and (almost) anything else leaves the `v`:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> v getcmdtype() is# ':' && getcmdline() is# 'v' ? 'e' : 'v'
```

Substitute `e` with `edit` for readability, or `vi` or `split` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: @filbranden good point. Fixed (I think)